# Why is the ${basedir} NLog configuration not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nlog

Why I cannot use ${basedir} nlog.config in my production server? If I use `fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"`, nlog does not log the message info, but if I change to something like `fileName="C:/logs/${shortdate}.log"` it will log the message info

my nlog.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>    
    <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="f" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Controller:

```csh
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        logger.Debug("Test NLog");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the account (App Pool / Network Service / custom) that your application is running under have permission to write to the logs folder?  Does the logs folder already exist?  Does that account have permission to create the folder in `${basedir}`?

Comment: @BrendanGreen How to check App Pool / Custom account permission? If I right click the application folder and click Security tab, there is only Network Service account and its permission is set to Read only

Comment: Well, how are you running the application?  Is it via IIS or IIS Express, or something else?  It all depends on your development environment, which you'll need to provide some more detail on.

Comment: I published the web using Web Deploy Package, then from IIS 6 Manager, right click Default Web Site - Deploy - Import Application and browse the zip package. I run under Windows Server 2008 and IE 9 this is my production environment. As in my question, the ${basedir} is not working in production server.

Comment: I think IIS6 runs ASP.NET under the `NETWORK SERVICE` account.  On your Windows Server 2008 box, you'll need to grant this account permission to write/modify your `logs` folder (which is presume is a sub-folder of your web root).  If you want the `logs` folder created automatically by NLog, you'll need to grant these permissions to the web root instead.

Comment: @BrendanGreen thank you, now it works, you could add it as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue is related to file permission.  Short story: the user that the web application is running as does not have permission to write the log files.

Depending on the version of .NET and the version of IIS, there are a variety of users that it could be.

For IIS 6, I would say that the web application is running as the `NETWORK SERVICE` account.

Therefore, you will need to grant this user permission to **write/modify** the `logs` folder (which I presume is a sub-folder of the web root).  If you want the `logs` folder to be created automatically by NLog, you'll need to grant these permissions to the web root instead.