# ASP.NET MVC 4 using nlog3.2.1 in iis6 won't update after I change setting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-6, nlog

My environment is iis6, build in ASP.NET MVC 4 and .NET Framework4, version of NLog is 3.2.1, installed by NuGet.
My NLog.config like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <variable name="Layout" value="${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${logger} | ${message} ${newline}"/>
  <variable name="LayoutFatal" value="${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${logger} | ${message} | ${exception:format=tostring} ${newline}"/>
  <variable name="LogTxtLocation" value="${basedir}/App_Data/Logs/${shortdate}/${logger}.txt"/>
  <variable name="LogTxtLocationFatal" value="${basedir}/App_Data/Logs/${shortdate}/FatalFile.txt"/>

  <targets>
    <target name="File" xsi:type="File" fileName="${LogTxtLocation}" layout="${Layout}" />
    <target name="FileFatal" xsi:type="File" fileName="${LogTxtLocationFatal}" layout="${LayoutFatal}"/>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="File" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

and I use nlog like this:

```
public static List<ws_VehicleInfo.RepairHistory> MyCarQuery(string sRegono, string sDateFrom, string sDateTo)
    {
        string log = "";
        List<ws_VehicleInfo.RepairHistory> repairHistoryList = new List<ws_VehicleInfo.RepairHistory>();
        try
        {
            logger.Info("start ws_getRepairHistory");
            repairHistoryList = new ws_VehicleInfo.ws_VehicleInfoPortTypeClient().ws_getRepairHistory(sKey, sRegono, sDateFrom, sDateTo, "").ToList();
            logger.Info("end ws_getRepairHistory");
            foreach (var item in repairHistoryList)
            {
                logger.Info("amount:" + item.amount);                    
                logger.Info("repairordertype:" + item.repairordertype);
                logger.Info("repairordertypeid:" + item.repairordertypeid);
                logger.Info("rono:" + item.rono);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Info(ex.ToString());
        }
        return repairHistoryList;
    }
```

class  is a object,and function ws_getRepairHistory would return a object contain multiple variables, and I expect to print all variables line by line.

But all I get like below

```
2015-05-28 11:22:24.8191 | INFO | Web.Models.DMS.BookingDMS | start ws_getRepairHistory 

2015-05-28 11:22:25.5066 | INFO | Web.Models.DMS.BookingDMS | end ws_getRepairHistory 

2015-05-28 11:22:25.5066 | INFO | Web.Models.DMS.BookingDMS | C,rono:B150300274-1 

2015-05-28 11:22:25.5066 | INFO | Web.Models.DMS.BookingDMS | A,rono:B150300274 

2015-05-28 11:22:25.5222 | INFO | Web.Models.DMS.BookingDMS | C,rono:B150300274-2
```

No matter how I change my code to log more detail, its still log the exactly same thing, I cant log anything more, even less, its repeatedly log the exactly same lines.

Which part do I do wrong?
Its fine when I run all these on my desktop but when I run on production server, I can only log the same thing.
I have check this article[Why is the ${basedir} NLog configuration not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729629/why-is-the-basedir-nlog-configuration-not-working)

But I can get log file, I just can't update the log content.
Please help.